# Regular expression to include all alphabets, numbers and special characters, except * and &

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm doing a text box validation that accepts all numbers, alphabets and also special characters, but not & and *.

I used `^[^/*/]*$` to escape the *, but it doesn't work. I admit I haven't used much of Regex while programming. Any help on the above would be appreciated.

Currently I just allow these set of characters

`a-zA-Z0-9 @&#%_',/?;\.\:\$\-/\n` and it works, but it also allows * , which I don't want.

Comment: Assuming *only* the [English alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_alphabet)?

Comment: @user2864740 Well he states in his question "all alphabets".

Comment: Yes, English alphabets only. Thanks for adding the comment. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @JacquesMarais And then goes on to show a very precise subset; once that is refined the next issue is that "all alphabets" is a small subset of "all Unicode" and "[all digits]" is different than "all Unicode numbers".

Answer (score 3):

Your regex escape is wrong. Use `\` instead of `/`. Also, `*` between `[` and `]` has no special meaning. So your regex should be `/[^*&]/g` (match anything, that is not `*` or `&`, `g`: search globally - optional)

Comment: This will match things like control characters.

Comment: @user2864740 I assume it's `and also special characters` stated by OP

Comment: I really doubt it and find it more likely that the OP has not thought about it. ^ is a "special character" (especially in half-tech lingo, such as passwords) while \f or \0 are "control characters". They are from different sets with entirely different purposes.

Comment: You (and probably the OP as well) are missing anchors, the regex is for a validation test not a search